# how do i compare 2 different string lists and return the difference if one is bigger?

Tags: python, list

please help me subtract the existing string from the list VideoList so we have a difference and should be formatted into a new list

```
Database = ["vill du ha","garry", "yao"]  #this is the list of the local data we have 
VideoList = ["garry", "vill du ha", "yao", "potato"] #this list has the same data as Database or more

#My code:
if len(VideoList) == len(Database):
    print("No new videos")
else:
 new_List = #i don't know what to do here but i want the list VideoLise to subtract the existing string in Data base and return what's left from VideoList as a List so the output should be NewList = ["potato"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the element of VideoList is present in Database or not
like

```
Database = ["vill du ha","garry", "yao"]
VideoList = ["garry", "vill du ha", "yao", "potato"] 

if len(VideoList) == len(Database):
    print("No new videos")
else:
    new_list=[]
    for element in VideoList:
        if not element in Database:
            new_list.append(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert both lists to sets and use the set difference operator:

```
diff = set(VideoList) - set(Database)
if diff:
    new_list = list(diff)
    print(new_list)
else:
    print("No new videos")
```

Output:

```
['potato']
```

Comment: but sets are unchangeable and i want it to be changeble

Comment: @BAHAAGAMER_HD the lists are not changed, you use `set()` function on them to find `diff`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `else` you can do:  `elif len(VideoList) > len(Database): print(f"you have {len(VideoList) - len(Database)} new videos")`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for using the set operator 'difference'. Convert your lists to sets, get the difference, and then convert the result back to a list:

```
>>> Database = ["vill du ha","garry", "yao"]
>>> VideoList = ["garry", "vill du ha", "yao", "potato"]
>>> new_list = list(set(VideoList).difference(set(Database)))
>>> new_list
['potato']
```

Answer (score 0):

check if exists in Database, if not append to a temporary list temp

```
def differ(VideoList, Database):
    temp = []
    for video in VideoList:
        if video not in Database:
            temp.append(video)
    return temp
```